# enzyme mount().find doesn't find anything

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

The following code:

```
const wrapper = mount(<Component />);
console.log('how to test this with jest', Object.keys(wrapper.find('h1')));
```

Logs `[]` so the find gives me an empty object. Opening it in the browser shows the `Component` with content `<h1>hello</h1>`

Is this the wrong selector to get `h1`?

The [documentation](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html) doesn't include finding elements by tag name but that selector would work with querySelector in JavaScript.

Trying `wrapper.find('.some-class')` gives me the same result even when Component returns `<h1 className="some-class">hello</h1>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapper.find returns a ReactWrapper that you use to test.

Lets say you wanted to test for the existence of an h1, you could do:

```
const wrapper = mount(<Component />);
expect(wrapper.find("h1").exists()).toBe(true);
```

Take a look at https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ for a full set of APIs.

Comment: I found [this documentation](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md#reactwrapper-api) a little more useful than the one in your answer. The object `mount` or `shallow` return seem to have no own properties so the log always logs an empty object that had me thinking the selector was wrong. Thank you for your answer.